# Page criteria not working with promotions filtering

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I am working on Smart target implementation with DD4T. I have created a promotion for a particular page in CME through Targeting tab. When I was trying to get promotions through resultset it is showing empty value. When I remove page trigger from promotion it is returning in the promotion resultset. Below are the code snippet used to get promotions:

```
QueryBuilder querybuilder = new QueryBuilder("catalog01", "en-US", puburi, regions);
querybuilder.addCriteria(new PageCriteria("10-100-64"));
ClaimStore claimStore = AmbientDataContext.getCurrentClaimStore();
String triggers = AmbientDataHelper.getTriggers(claimStore);
querybuilder.parseQueryString(triggers);
ResultSet results = querybuilder.execute();
```

Here results.getPromotions() is returning empty value if I have promotion with page tcm id 10-100-64. If I remove the page from promotion it is returning in the resultset. Can anyone point to the probable issue. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What namespace is PageCriteria, the old regular Broker Criteria API?  I don't think you can use that with the ST API. I'm surprised your code compiles.

Comment: Hi Nickoli, namespace for page criteria is com.tridion.smarttarget.query.builder.PageCriteria. During creation of promotion we have the option to select page to show that promotion, so I was sure that it will work. In fredhopper too, I can see page id as a scope trigger. It is compiling but unfortunately not returning any promotions.

Comment: Have you tried to manually create the URL query string for the FH webservice and study the raw response?  I recall Will Price had a few posts on how to do that.  This would allow you to narrow down on the actual cause.

Comment: Hi Nickoli, I have seen the difference between response returned for promotion with page trigger and without page trigger. And by analysing the response I can understand that fredhopper is not returning any promotion if page is defined for that promotion. I am not sure, if it is a default behaviour or something wrong with api call or configuration missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By analyzing the whole criteria through page preview of fredhopper I have found that page criteria was working fine with code mentioned. Only issue was with same name I had 2 pages and I have my promotions configured for wrong page.